# How do I fix this parser error with npm run buildf?

Tags: reactjs, npm

How do I fix this parser error with `npm` run build?

Can help me please!

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'rebuild' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.14.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prerebuild', 'rebuild', 'postrebuild' ]
5 info lifecycle resume@0.1.0~prerebuild: resume@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle resume@0.1.0~rebuild: resume@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle resume@0.1.0~rebuild: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle resume@0.1.0~rebuild: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\repos\github\resume\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\ticoi\bin;C:\Users\ticoi\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\ticoi\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\ticoi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ticoi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ticoi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\ticoi\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\ticoi\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle resume@0.1.0~rebuild: CWD: C:\repos\github\resume
10 silly lifecycle resume@0.1.0~rebuild: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run clean && npm install && npm run build' ]
11 silly lifecycle resume@0.1.0~rebuild: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle resume@0.1.0~rebuild: Failed to exec rebuild script
13 verbose stack Error: resume@0.1.0 rebuild: `npm run clean && npm install && npm run build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
14 verbose pkgid resume@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\repos\github\resume
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "rebuild"
18 verbose node v10.14.1
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error resume@0.1.0 rebuild: `npm run clean && npm install && npm run build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the resume@0.1.0 rebuild script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I work with reactjs and npm.

Comment: Hi the problem I am having is that when I run build i get an error. I did change some files but nothing near index.js or important. My changes were to html elements order...